# Populate jTable from Postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jtable

I am new to java swing, so don't mind if it's a very basic question.

The task is to get data from PostgreSQL database and populate it to `jTable`. I follow the example [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546332/populate-jtable-from-database-on-login). But there is still something missing. I am receiving data in console from the database but not in the table. Here is the code

```
DefaultTableModel model_search=DefaultTableModel)jTable_Search.getModel();
String connection_string="jdbc:postgresql://"+host_db+":"+port_db+"/"+name_db+"";

    try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_string,username_db, password_db)) {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql_beacons="query to database";
        ResultSet resultSet_beacons = statement.executeQuery(sql_beacons);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet_beacons.getMetaData();
        int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        while (resultSet_beacons.next()){
           System.out.printf(resultSet_beacons.getString("mac")+" ");
           Object[] objects = new Object[]{resultSet_beacons.getString("mac")};
           model_search.addRow(objects);  
        }                                                 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and include the library from `http://technojeeves.com/index.php/22-resultset-to-tablemodel`

In your code, this statment will populate data to jTable.

```
String sql="Query to database";
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql); 
jTable_Search.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```